# Dropdown menu image instead of the default arrow image

Tags: html, css

is there a way that i can change the arrow image of a dropdown box and put a defined one in css/html?

Comment: Yes, there is a way. (we need more information)

Comment: @thirtydot, I think the question is clear. 
@Donald, I dont think so, because it depends browser and even operating system

Comment: @Faith, so even if i put my own image(which i'm struggling to put) each browser will change the arrow in its own specific way?

Comment: @Faith: I guess it's clear if he means of a `<select>` tag. When I wrote my comment, I thought he meant the "arrow image" of XYZ JavaScript drop down menu. Obviously, not a *clear* question :)

Comment: Stop calling the man 'Faith'! It's Fatih, a very common name in Turkey (e.g. Fatih Terim, the football manager)!

Comment: Hey sorry for mistyping his name Scatt.. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There aren't any html/css ways of getting round this - as Fatih stated in his comment, it's dependent on the operating system/browser combo. There are various JavaScript ways though.

This one looks great to me, if you can pick the code out if it: <strike>http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/branches/labs/selectmenu/index.html</strike> (link dead)

This is quite nice too: http://uniformjs.com/

Of course, you'll be able to change the graphics behind these so you can make them look how you wish.

---

EDIT

Although that link's dead, there is information on what could be found [here](http://filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/) and source files are still available on GitHub [here](https://github.com/pixeldrew/jqueryui-selectmenu).

Comment: first link obsolete now :|

Comment: Answer updated with fresh links referring to the original. Thanks for the heads-up.