# How do you add an add image as drop down arrow?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I created a application with a drop down arrow, but the size of the arrow is too small.

So  I decided to enlarge the size of the arrow. I need to add an image instead of arrow.

Is it possible to add image or resize the arrow?

My current CSS is below.

```
.custom-select:after {
        content: "â–¼";
        content-size:20;
        position: absolute;
        top: -83%;
        right: 6%;
        bottom: 0;
        font-size: 60%;
        line-height:30px;
        line-width:100px;
        padding: 0 10px;
        background:#03498A;
        color: white;

        height:40px;
        pointer-events:none;

        -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0;
        -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0;
        border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0;
    }
<label class="custom-select" style="width:40%" onClick="birthday()">

   <select name="mydropdown" id="gender" placeholder="Gender">

   <option value="">Gender</option>

<option  value="Male">Male</option>

<option  value="Female">Female</option>
</select>
</label>
```

Comment: Hai! Please consider properly indenting your code to improve readability. It would also be a good idea to capitalize the letter "I", and to add spaces between sentences.

Comment: @code Gray i update sir do u understrnd my question ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002800/dropdown-menu-image-instead-of-the-default-arrow-image

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this solution, worked for me and looks very nice. It's vital to wrap your  element inside the div, and then apply formatting.

Also, make sure that your arrow picture has a transparent background (or at least the same background color as the dropdown you're using).

The ".drop_list select" CSS may look a bit heavy, but it's all needed (except padding and font-size) to make it look good on all browsers/devices. Tested this on desktop/tablet/mobile phones, and works great. You might need to make a few modifications to the CSS to match your site though.

HTML:

```
<div class="drop_list">
    <select name="mydropdown" id="gender" placeholder="Gender">
        <option value="">Gender</option>
        <option value="Male">Male</option>
        <option value="Female">Female</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.drop_list {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: no-repeat #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background-image:url('YOUR_TRANSPARENT_BACKGROUND_ARROW.png');
    background-position: top right; 
}

.drop_list select{
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    background: transparent;
    padding: 3px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    height: 30px;
    width: 120%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

You should consider using a base64 arrow image for this, one less request to the server. Feel free to use mine for this:

```
background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABkAAAAeCAYAAADZ7LXbAAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwEAmpwYAAAKT2lDQ1BQaG90b3Nob3AgSUNDIHByb2ZpbGUAAHjanVNnVFPpFj333vRCS4iAlEtvUhUIIFJCi4AUkSYqIQkQSoghodkVUcERRUUEG8igiAOOjoCMFVEsDIoK2AfkIaKOg6OIisr74Xuja9a89+bN/rXXPues852zzwfACAyWSDNRNYAMqUIeEeCDx8TG4eQuQIEKJHAAEAizZCFz/SMBAPh+PDwrIsAHvgABeNMLCADATZvAMByH/w/qQplcAYCEAcB0kThLCIAUAEB6jkKmAEBGAYCdmCZTAKAEAGDLY2LjAFAtAGAnf+bTAICd+Jl7AQBblCEVAaCRACATZYhEAGg7AKzPVopFAFgwABRmS8Q5ANgtADBJV2ZIALC3AMDOEAuyAAgMADBRiIUpAAR7AGDIIyN4AISZABRG8lc88SuuEOcqAAB4mbI8uSQ5RYFbCC1xB1dXLh4ozkkXKxQ2YQJhmkAuwnmZGTKBNA/g88wAAKCRFRHgg/P9eM4Ors7ONo62Dl8t6r8G/yJiYuP+5c+rcEAAAOF0ftH+LC+zGoA7BoBt/qIl7gRoXgugdfeLZrIPQLUAoOnaV/Nw+H48PEWhkLnZ2eXk5NhKxEJbYcpXff5nwl/AV/1s+X48/Pf14L7iJIEyXYFHBPjgwsz0TKUcz5IJhGLc5o9H/LcL//wd0yLESWK5WCoU41EScY5EmozzMqUiiUKSKcUl0v9k4t8s+wM+3zUAsGo+AXuRLahdYwP2SycQWHTA4vcAAPK7b8HUKAgDgGiD4c93/+8//UegJQCAZkmScQAAXkQkLlTKsz/HCAAARKCBKrBBG/TBGCzABhzBBdzBC/xgNoRCJMTCQhBCCmSAHHJgKayCQiiGzbAdKmAv1EAdNMBRaIaTcA4uwlW4Dj1wD/phCJ7BKLyBCQRByAgTYSHaiAFiilgjjggXmYX4IcFIBBKLJCDJiBRRIkuRNUgxUopUIFVIHfI9cgI5h1xGupE7yAAygvyGvEcxlIGyUT3UDLVDuag3GoRGogvQZHQxmo8WoJvQcrQaPYw2oefQq2gP2o8+Q8cwwOgYBzPEbDAuxsNCsTgsCZNjy7EirAyrxhqwVqwDu4n1Y8+xdwQSgUXACTYEd0IgYR5BSFhMWE7YSKggHCQ0EdoJNwkDhFHCJyKTqEu0JroR+cQYYjIxh1hILCPWEo8TLxB7iEPENyQSiUMyJ7mQAkmxpFTSEtJG0m5SI+ksqZs0SBojk8naZGuyBzmULCAryIXkneTD5DPkG+Qh8lsKnWJAcaT4U+IoUspqShnlEOU05QZlmDJBVaOaUt2ooVQRNY9aQq2htlKvUYeoEzR1mjnNgxZJS6WtopXTGmgXaPdpr+h0uhHdlR5Ol9BX0svpR+iX6AP0dwwNhhWDx4hnKBmbGAcYZxl3GK+YTKYZ04sZx1QwNzHrmOeZD5lvVVgqtip8FZHKCpVKlSaVGyovVKmqpqreqgtV81XLVI+pXlN9rkZVM1PjqQnUlqtVqp1Q61MbU2epO6iHqmeob1Q/pH5Z/YkGWcNMw09DpFGgsV/jvMYgC2MZs3gsIWsNq4Z1gTXEJrHN2Xx2KruY/R27iz2qqaE5QzNKM1ezUvOUZj8H45hx+Jx0TgnnKKeX836K3hTvKeIpG6Y0TLkxZVxrqpaXllirSKtRq0frvTau7aedpr1Fu1n7gQ5Bx0onXCdHZ4/OBZ3nU9lT3acKpxZNPTr1ri6qa6UbobtEd79up+6Ynr5egJ5Mb6feeb3n+hx9L/1U/W36p/VHDFgGswwkBtsMzhg8xTVxbzwdL8fb8VFDXcNAQ6VhlWGX4YSRudE8o9VGjUYPjGnGXOMk423GbcajJgYmISZLTepN7ppSTbmmKaY7TDtMx83MzaLN1pk1mz0x1zLnm+eb15vft2BaeFostqi2uGVJsuRaplnutrxuhVo5WaVYVVpds0atna0l1rutu6cRp7lOk06rntZnw7Dxtsm2qbcZsOXYBtuutm22fWFnYhdnt8Wuw+6TvZN9un2N/T0HDYfZDqsdWh1+c7RyFDpWOt6azpzuP33F9JbpL2dYzxDP2DPjthPLKcRpnVOb00dnF2e5c4PziIuJS4LLLpc+Lpsbxt3IveRKdPVxXeF60vWdm7Obwu2o26/uNu5p7ofcn8w0nymeWTNz0MPIQ+BR5dE/C5+VMGvfrH5PQ0+BZ7XnIy9jL5FXrdewt6V3qvdh7xc+9j5yn+M+4zw33jLeWV/MN8C3yLfLT8Nvnl+F30N/I/9k/3r/0QCngCUBZwOJgUGBWwL7+Hp8Ib+OPzrbZfay2e1BjKC5QRVBj4KtguXBrSFoyOyQrSH355jOkc5pDoVQfujW0Adh5mGLw34MJ4WHhVeGP45wiFga0TGXNXfR3ENz30T6RJZE3ptnMU85ry1KNSo+qi5qPNo3ujS6P8YuZlnM1VidWElsSxw5LiquNm5svt/87fOH4p3iC+N7F5gvyF1weaHOwvSFpxapLhIsOpZATIhOOJTwQRAqqBaMJfITdyWOCnnCHcJnIi/RNtGI2ENcKh5O8kgqTXqS7JG8NXkkxTOlLOW5hCepkLxMDUzdmzqeFpp2IG0yPTq9MYOSkZBxQqohTZO2Z+pn5mZ2y6xlhbL+xW6Lty8elQfJa7OQrAVZLQq2QqboVFoo1yoHsmdlV2a/zYnKOZarnivN7cyzytuQN5zvn//tEsIS4ZK2pYZLVy0dWOa9rGo5sjxxedsK4xUFK4ZWBqw8uIq2Km3VT6vtV5eufr0mek1rgV7ByoLBtQFr6wtVCuWFfevc1+1dT1gvWd+1YfqGnRs+FYmKrhTbF5cVf9go3HjlG4dvyr+Z3JS0qavEuWTPZtJm6ebeLZ5bDpaql+aXDm4N2dq0Dd9WtO319kXbL5fNKNu7g7ZDuaO/PLi8ZafJzs07P1SkVPRU+lQ27tLdtWHX+G7R7ht7vPY07NXbW7z3/T7JvttVAVVN1WbVZftJ+7P3P66Jqun4lvttXa1ObXHtxwPSA/0HIw6217nU1R3SPVRSj9Yr60cOxx++/p3vdy0NNg1VjZzG4iNwRHnk6fcJ3/ceDTradox7rOEH0x92HWcdL2pCmvKaRptTmvtbYlu6T8w+0dbq3nr8R9sfD5w0PFl5SvNUyWna6YLTk2fyz4ydlZ19fi753GDborZ752PO32oPb++6EHTh0kX/i+c7vDvOXPK4dPKy2+UTV7hXmq86X23qdOo8/pPTT8e7nLuarrlca7nuer21e2b36RueN87d9L158Rb/1tWeOT3dvfN6b/fF9/XfFt1+cif9zsu72Xcn7q28T7xf9EDtQdlD3YfVP1v+3Njv3H9qwHeg89HcR/cGhYPP/pH1jw9DBY+Zj8uGDYbrnjg+OTniP3L96fynQ89kzyaeF/6i/suuFxYvfvjV69fO0ZjRoZfyl5O/bXyl/erA6xmv28bCxh6+yXgzMV70VvvtwXfcdx3vo98PT+R8IH8o/2j5sfVT0Kf7kxmTk/8EA5jz/GMzLdsAAAAgY0hSTQAAeiUAAICDAAD5/wAAgOkAAHUwAADqYAAAOpgAABdvkl/FRgAAAKRJREFUeNrs1TEKwkAQheEvIoI2nsk7qFdIq1hoJ3gCC5sUVpY23sDKXnvrYOUBbGITG0kQjQriPlgYhmF/3ryFjbIs82nVfEEBEiAB8k+Q+q1IkqSDNVq4lMy3scIkjuP0FSdbjNHMLys6OwyQVlnXEsOS2QP6OL8jkzlmd70jus86eBT8FIu8PqGXg6oFX6ARGthgX+V1ReFnDJAACZAfhFwHAJI7HF2lZGQaAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC);
```

Comment: You should really use CSS if possible, but if you must use background image in html, you must use it with the div element, not the <select>.

Your HTML would be:
`<div class="dropdown_div" style="background-image:url('s.png');">
    <select name="mydropdown" id="gender" placeholder="Gender">
        <option value="">Gender</option>
        <option value="Male">Male</option>
        <option value="Female">Female</option>
    </select>
</div>`

But you should still use the rest of CSS in the original answer. It's needed to hide the original browser generated arrow.

Comment: You should correct the classname you applied to the div. Or correct the classname. Then your code will work.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
<label>Arrow code/image</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
select.dropdownPager
{
background: url(images/combo.png) no-repeat right;
width: 60px;
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 12px;
outline: none;
height: 23px;
border: none;
background-color: #fff;
display: block;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
border-bottom: #ccc 1px solid;
border-left: #ccc 1px solid;
border-top: #ccc 1px solid;
border-right: #ccc 1px solid;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
   }
```